# Regression of a time series difference

Tags: regression, time-series, cointegration, differencing

Suppose $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are two time series. I regress $y(t)$ against $x(t)$, and obtain
$$y(t)=ax(t)+b+z(t) $$
for some regression constants $a, b$ and residue $z(t)$. Define $\Delta u(t):=u(t+1)-u(t)$ for a given time series $u(t)$. Now regress $\Delta y(t)$ against $\Delta x(t)$. It seems the following should hold
$$\Delta y(t) \sim a\Delta x(t)$$
However, it seems the actual regression coefficient turns out to be $0$.

Can someone give a model to account for this phenomenon? Is there where cointegration should be used?

Comment: Hi: It's not clear ( to me atleast ) how the differenced $u(t)$ plays a role in the regression in differences ?

Comment: @mlofton: $u$ is used to defined the difference operator $\Delta$.

Comment: But the differenced $u_t$ is not in the model where you say that the following should hold ?

Comment: @mlofton: $u$ is an arbitrary time series.

Comment: But what does the $u_t$ have to do with the  $\Delta y(t) \sim a \Delta x(t) $ ?

Comment: @mlofton: Let me make it absolutely clear. $\Delta$ is defined to be an endomorphism (or operator) on the set of all time series such that for an arbitrary element $u(t)$ of that set, $\Delta u(t):=u(t)-u(t-1)$.

Comment: Now I get what you're doing. You didn't include $\Delta z_{t}$ in your final model so that confused me. Check this paper out ( at the bottom ) for what can happen when you do that. If the original model is correctly specified, then you've overdifferenced. If it's not correctly  specifiied, then you want to look the concept of cointegration. Spurious regression may also be an issue if y_t and x_t are of different order ( a different issue from overdifferencing ). https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332621968_Over-Differencing_and_Forecasting_with_Non-Stationary_Time_Series_Data

Comment: and my apologies for continuing to ask about $u_t$. I thought it was the error term in the differenced model or possibly overdifferenced model qhwn the actual error is $\Delta z_{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

That's the main difference between math and statistics in time series. If you assume that the actual data generating process (DGP) of ***$y(t)$*** is your equation, then your reasoning applies. But if it's not, then many things may be happening. Basically you are trying to combine two time series that are supposed to have two independent DGPs, which come with noise and/or trend. Those elements are distorting your model in differences, and the noise of that model is greater than the one in levels. You should indeed use cointegration models, for example de Error Correction Model (ECM) or the ARDL-ECM Model, to verify if the variables are in fact related or not.

Comment: I am not denying the linear model I gave is not the real model. That is why I said "seems". I am quite interested in seeing an explicit model to explain this phenomenon.